# Simplest responsive grid fail

Tags: yui-pure-css

I am trying to create a responsive grid with a single column containing two adjacent boxes.  ⅓ columns on the left and ⅔ columns on the right. Here's the non-responsive version on codepen at http://codepen.io/htmlcheats/pen/OWMobO:

```
<div class="pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-1-3" style="background-color: red; height: 10em;">
        Box 1 - 33.3% width uses pure-1-3 style
    </div><!-- .pure-u-1-3 -->
    <div class="pure-u-2-3" style="background-color: teal; height: 10em;">
        Box 2 - 66.6% width uses pure-2-3 style
    </div><!-- .pure-u-2-3 -->      
</div><!-- .pure-g -->
```

It works as expected. When I squish them together or stretch them they remain adjacent.

Here's the responsive version (codepen at http://codepen.io/htmlcheats/pen/OWMobO):

```
<div class="pure-g">    
    <div class="pure-sm-md-1-3 pure-u-md-1-3 pure-u-lg-1-3 pure-u-1" style="background-color: red; height: 10em;">
        Box 1 - 33.3% width uses pure-1-3 style
    </div><!-- .pure-u-1-3 -->
    <div class="pure-sm-md-2-3 pure-u-md-2-3 pure-u-lg-2-3 pure-u-1" style="background-color: teal; height: 10em;">
        Box 2 - 66.6% width uses pure-2-3 style
    </div><!-- .pure-u-2-3 -->  
</div><!-- .pure-g -->
```

When I squash the page they still remain atop each other. If I understand correctly they should collapse and create a single column with the red box standing on top of the teal one.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two codepen links in your question (the unresponsive and responsive one) are the same - they both link to the unresponsive version of your example, but I found what I believe was your [responsive example](http://codepen.io/htmlcheats/pen/RKrYVV).

Anyway, to enable responsive grids in purecss, you have to include the separate responsive grids CSS file as well as the base purecss file. From the [responsive grids documentation](http://purecss.io/grids/#pure-responsive-grids):

> Since media queries cannot be over-written, we do not include the grid system as part of pure.css. You'll have to pull it in as a separate CSS file. You can do this by adding the following  tag to your page.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/grids-responsive-old-ie-min.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/grids-responsive-min.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I took the responsive version of your pen and added the links to the responsive CSS files (code block above) and it [works as expected](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apNXWB). At the end of the day, your CSS links should look like this:

```
<!-- base purecss file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-CCTZv2q9I9m3UOxRLaJneXrrqKwUNOzZ6NGEUMwHtShDJ+nCoiXJCAgi05KfkLGY" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- purecss responsive grids -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/grids-responsive-old-ie-min.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/grids-responsive-min.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I swear I went over the documentation about 235 times.  I appear to be a liar. And sorry about the duped link. Spent a lot of time on the question; don't know why the brain fart. I wish there was some kind of Donate or Tip mechanism to thank you. I guess I'll just have to say.. thank you.